# Is there a way to count how many entries in a given column have a particular value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, time-series

I have a spreadsheet which keeps track of duels between two players in a game. Each row has the number of the match and the winner, given by their initial, X or Y. I want to know if it's possible to get a percentage for how many of the total matches have been won by player X or Y, and maybe make some sort of pie chart.

If that IS possible, then I'd also like to know if it's possible to group results by date. Imagine if there was a third column with the date of each match, would it be possible to create a pie chart for each month? October, November, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en), e.g. to get a percentage for how many of the total matches have been won by player X: `=(COUNTIF(A2:A10,"=X")/COUNTA(A2:A10)*100`.

For the grouping, I think you need to use [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en) ([`GROUP BY`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Group_By)).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `QUERY`?

Comment: E.g. `=query(J:L,"select count(K) group by L, J", 0)` where `J` is the winner name, `K` the date, `L = MONTH(K)`.

Answer (score 1):

As often, I suggest a pivot table. For the months and pie charts however I would recommend in addition a column to indicate the month, say just the number with something like:

```
=month(D2)
```

in E2 copied down to suit.

[image: WA51790 example]

The pie charts can be plotted by selecting such as shown in the image for February. Percentages won by player can be derived from the Grand Total row (5/9 and 4/9 in the example).